# Python, tkinter, is there a external module I can use to import my own font for my program?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I know their is no inbuilt function with tkinter to use external font for Unix based OS's, but is there any way to do it with a separate module? I saw pyglet but that didn't seem like it was  with the caveat that the system had to support that

I've looked all over the internet and even searched on reddit but nothing came up. I want to us tkinter for this project just because I like the module.